# Reference C++/CLI class library (compiled dll) in C# project

Tags: c#, dll, reference, c++-cli

I have a very simple C++ class library that has two account types in it called **Checking** and **Savings**.  I have built this project and compiled it into a .dll called Accounts. I have referenced the **Accounts.dll** in my C# Console application.  To no avail, I am trying to use the static classes **deposit** and **withdraw** from the **Savings** and **Checking** classes respectively.  I do not see the functions show up in the Object Browser or Intellisense and I am not able to get it to build when I try to access those functions, otherwise I am able to build and run when I comment out the call to mySavings.deposit(arg1,arg2)...

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly here?  I often reference .dlls from other projects and third parties but this is the first time referencing a C++ .dll within a C# project.

C++ Class Library

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;

namespace Accounts {

  public ref class Savings
  {
    public:
        unsigned accountNumber;
        double balance;
        static double deposit(Savings s, double amount)
        {
            s.balance += amount;
            return s.balance;
        }
  };

  public ref class Checking
  {
    public:
        unsigned accountNumber;
        double balance;
        static double withdraw(Checking c, double amount)
        {
            c.balance -= amount;
            return c.balance;
        }
  };
}
```

C# Console Application that references the above compiled dynamic link library

```
using Accounts;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Savings mySavings = new Savings();  // works but object is empty
    mySavings.deposit(mySavings, 100);  // still breaks
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error: 'Accounts.Savings' does not contain a definition for 'deposit' and no extension method 'deposit' accepting a first argument of type 'Accounts.Savings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking that C# can access C++ classes... it can't.  But C++/CLI can create .NET types that C# can use.  However, these follow the rules of .NET, which are sometimes different from C++.

First, you must use `ref class` (or `ref struct` or `value class` or `value struct`) in your C++/CLI code:

```
public ref class Savings
```

Then, you need to initialize your C# reference to point to an object.  Simply declaring a variable in C# is not enough to get an object default constructed (not for reference types, where the variable will be `null` or uninitialized, and not for value types, where the content will be all-zero or uninitialized, with no constructor called).

```
Savings mySavings = new Savings();
```

After that, you'll discover that C++/CLI can't reference .NET reference types except via tracking handles... so instead of

```
Savings&
```

you need

```
Savings% // tracking reference, but C# doesn't know what to do
         // with a function whose parameter is like this
```

or

```
Savings^ // tracking pointer, C# likes it fine, C++/CLI will need -> to access members
```

Finally, the syntax for calling a static function from C# is

```
Savings.deposit(mySavings, 100);
// ^^ class name, not object
```

But that probably should be a non-static member anyway, right?.

Comment: Ok Ben, that helped.  Now I can see the accountNumber and balance but I still don't see my function.  I had to remove the & from the class to get it to compile but I am missing whatever that is that will allow the functions to be seen...  I have updated my code above.

Comment: @user2146538: You need `Savings^` for the function argument, and `->` when using it.  This is because C# variables, like in Java, are actually pointers.  (For reference types only, but value types shouldn't be used when there are invariants, only for simple data containers)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  Never seen anything like it!  :-)